# Как узнать шестнадцатеричный код латинского символа в формате UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Необходимо закодировать каждый символ из введённой строки в шестеричный номер кодировки UTF-8. Затем все полученные значения логически сложить. Когда я кодирую кириллицу, то получаю как мне и нужно число в шестнадцатеричном формате:

```
>> string = 'Г'
>> number = string.encode('utf-8')
>> b'\xd0\x93'
```

Но когда я кодирую английский символ или число, то в результате получаю его же.

```
>> string = 'W'
>> number = string.encode('utf-8')
>> b'W'
```

Как можно получить шестнадцатеричное представление латинских символов и чисел?

Comment: hex(ord('W')) ?

Comment: @Alpensin Да, вроде оно, спасибо. Только не могу понять, почему если воспользоваться ` hex(ord('г')) ` получим 0x433, а если ` 'г'.encode('utf-8') ` , то  b'\xd0\xb3'?

Comment: @Alpensin это будет не utf-8, а просто юникод

Comment: А utf-8 будет так: `binascii.hexlify('г'.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @insolor Получается мне вообще не нужно переводить в utf8, так как в python 3 в данной кодировке? Но как тогда логически сложить или умножить два символа?

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @leach зачем вам вообще складывать и умножать символы?

Comment: @andreymal Дали ТЗ в котором нужно рассчитать контрольную сумму путём логического сложения последовательности произвольных символов, которые прежде по ТЗ необходимо кодировать в utf8

Comment: @leach просто `sum(s.encode('utf-8'))` что ли?

Comment: @andreymal Не совсем, мне нужно использовать бинарный "ИЛИ". Не уверен, что sum даёт правильный результат.

Comment: @leach, `from functools import reduce` `reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, s.encode('utf-8'))`. Или просто циклом проходите и аккумулируете логическую сумму в какой-то переменной.

Comment: @insolor но это уже какая-то странная контрольная сумма, на достаточно длинном тексте все биты просто станут единицами...

Comment: @andreymal а, ну может xor имелся в виду, тогда ^ вместо |

Comment: По заданию именно ИЛИ, но спасибо вам за помощь. Сейчас попробую разобраться с новой информацией)

Comment: @insolor Извините за беспокойство, не могли бы вы написать `reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, s.encode('utf-8'))` в виде обычной функции?

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для логического сложения вам не нужно шестнадцатеричное представление, нужны числовые представления байт. `b'W'` - это просто визуальное ("человекочитаемое") представление, эквивалентное `b'\x57'` (`b'W' == b'\x57'` даст `True`). Более того, `b'W'[0]` будет равно `87` и равно `0x57`, т.е. просто обращаясь к отдельному байту из набора байт получаем числовое представление этого байта (что нам и нужно, см. первое предложение).

Для получения логической "суммы" всех байт, нужно просто пройти по последовательности байт, каждый байт "прибавлять" битовым "или" к результирующей переменной:

```
result = 0

for b in text.encode('utf-8'):
     result |= b  # То же самое что result = result | b

print(hex(result))
```

Если в функциональном стиле, то так:

```
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, text.encode('utf-8'))
# Функция reduce объединяет последовательность из второго аргумента функцией из первого аргумента
# Для примера, если первым аргументом передать функцию, суммирующую два аргумента,
# то в результате получится сумма всех объектов последовательности
```

или

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
# or_ - функция, соответствующая оператору |
# То есть or_(X, Y) == X | Y

result = reduce(or_, text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но всё равно немного не то, что нужно. С английскими символами и числами всё хорошо, но вот при вводе кириллицы второе шестнадцатеричное число не верное. Например при вводе символа 'я', необходимо получить D1 и 8F (как при простом `text.encode('utf-8')`) , но первая функция выводит D1 и DF

Comment: Нужно результат в конце только смотреть, а не выводить в процессе выполнения for, DF - это и есть результат сложения байт буквы "я": https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze2SJ.png

Comment: Но мне к сожалению нужно получить именно последовательность, так как если строка будет состоять из символов "Fя", то последовательность лог. сложения будет не верным. Сначала сложатся 2 числа от символа я (D1 и 8F), а затем уже F (46). А необходимо так: 46 ИЛИ D1 ИЛИ 8F

Comment: @leach , `(D1 и 8F), а затем уже F (46). А необходимо так: 46 | D1 | 8F` - результат будет одинаковым. Это как `(2 + 3) + 4` ("а затем уже 4") и `2 + 3 + 4`.